# Test Python shell jobs scripts: dev endpoint?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, shell

I would like to set up a Python shell job as an ETL job. This job would do some basic data cleaning.

For now, I have a script that runs locally. I would like to test this script (or parts of it). I tried to setup a dev endpoint like it's explained here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint-tutorial-repl.html

Everything went fine, I can ssh into the machine. But with this tutorial, I get a "gluepyspark" shell. And this shell isn't compatible with the AWS data wrangler library: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler.

I would like to know if it's possible to setup a dev endpoint to test python shell jobs. Alternatively, I could also accept a workflow to test python shell jobs.